# 'A plugin by the name "Example\Segment" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Router\RoutePluginManager

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am currently working through the Zend 3 tutorial. The only difference is I am using an Examples table/class instead of Albums. Everything appears to be as per spec except I am getting the following error every time I try to access the dev server:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message
>   'A plugin by the name "Example\Segment" was not found in the plugin
>   manager Zend\Router\RoutePluginManager' in
>   C:\Websites\ZEND2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\AbstractPluginManager.php:133
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Websites\ZEND2\vendor\zendframework\zend-router\src\SimpleRouteStack.php(280):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('Example\Segment',
>   Array) #1
>   C:\Websites\ZEND2\vendor\zendframework\zend-router\src\Http\TreeRouteStack.php(201):
>   Zend\Router\SimpleRouteStack->routeFromArray(Array) #2
>   C:\Websites\ZEND2\vendor\zendframework\zend-router\src\Http\TreeRouteStack.php(151):
>   Zend\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack->routeFromArray(Array) #3
>   C:\Websites\ZEND2\vendor\zendframework\zend-router\src\SimpleRouteStack.php(142):
>   Zend\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack->addRoute('example', Array) #4
>   C:\Websites\ZEND2\vendor\zendframework\zend-router\src\SimpleRouteStack.php(86):
>   Zend\Router\SimpleRouteStack->addRoutes(Array) in
>   C:\Websites\ZEND2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\AbstractPluginManager.php
>   on line 133

ExampleController.php

```
namespace Example\Controller;

use Example\Model\ExampleTable;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class ExampleController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $table;

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel([
            'examples' => $this->table->fetchAll(),
        ]);
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
    }

     public function __construct(ExampleTable $table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
    }
}
```

ExampleTable.php

```
<?php 

namespace Example\Model;

use RuntimeException;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGatewayInterface;

class ExampleTable
{
    private $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        return $this->tableGateway->select();
    }

    public function getExample($id)
    {
        $id = (int) $id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(['id' => $id]);
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (! $row) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Could not find row with identifier %d',
                $id
            ));
        }

        return $row;
    }

    public function saveExample(Example $example)
    {
        $data = [
            'name' => $example->name,
            'description'  => $example->description,
            'web_url'  => $example->web_url,
        ];

        $id = (int) $example->id;

        if ($id === 0) {
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
            return;
        }

        if (! $this->getExample($id)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Cannot update example with identifier %d; does not exist',
                $id
            ));
        }

        $this->tableGateway->update($data, ['id' => $id]);
    }

    public function deleteExample($id)
    {
        $this->tableGateway->delete(['id' => (int) $id]);
    }
}
```

module.config.php

```
<?php

namespace Example;

return [

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file:
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'example' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/example[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\ExampleController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'example' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Module.php

```
<?php

namespace Example;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '\config\module.config.php';
    }

    // Add this method:
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                Model\ExampleTable::class => function($container) {
                    $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\ExampleTableGateway::class);
                    return new Model\ExampleTable($tableGateway);
                },
                Model\ExampleTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                    $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\Example());
                    return new TableGateway('example', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ],
        ];
    }

     public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                Controller\ExampleController::class => function($container) {
                    return new Controller\ExampleController(
                        $container->get(Model\ExampleTable::class)
                    );
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Example.php

```
namespace Example\Model;

class Example
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $description;
    public $web_url

    public function exchangeArray(array $data)
    {
        $this->id     = !empty($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->name = !empty($data['name']) ? $data['name'] : null;
        $this->description  = !empty($data['description']) ? $data['description'] : null;
        $this->web_url  = !empty($data['web_url']) ? $data['web_url'] : null;
    }
}
```

modules.config.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

/**
 * List of enabled modules for this application.
 *
 * This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
 */
return [
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\Db',
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application',
    'Example',
];
```

I have included everything as iam really not sure where the problem is. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please only include the code necessary to fix the issue. See the Stack Overflow guidelines [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In your `module.config.php` write `'segment'` in place of `Segment::class`

Answer (score 15):

Your `module.config.php` file needs a:

```
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
```

declaration near the top to create the `Segment` alias that you use later on in the file. At the moment, because this doesn't exist, PHP is looking for that class in your declared namespace (so `Example\Segment`), which doesn't exist.

Comment: Nice, worked and removes errors! It is so frustrating, when, while you trying to do your first steps, holes like that appears under your feet.  Thank you Tim